# Proof for sum of this infinite derivative series....

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives, geometric-series

I was recently watching a [Numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/user/numberphile) [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=daro6K6mym8) when I saw this 'formula' :

> $$S = \sum \limits_{n=1} ^ {\infty} n\,x^{n-1} = \dfrac {1} {\big(x-1\big)^2} \,\,\,\forall\,\,\, |x| < 1$$

I was amazed to see this and it immediately struck to my mind that it is really an infinite derivative series:

$$S=\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac {d}{dx} x^n = \dfrac {d}{dx}\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n$$

Now applying the sum for infinite Geometric Series when $|r|<1$ ($r = $ common ratio)  :

$$S = \dfrac{d}{dx}\dfrac{1}{1-x} = \dfrac{1}{\big(1-x\big)^2}$$

I am really a beginner at Calculus, so the first question I want to ask is :

> Is my derivation for the sum $S$ mathematically correct ?

Though my final expression comes out good, there still might be chance of some mistake, so please help me.

Also,

> Is there any other way of deriving this result besides Calculus? Is this result even linked to Calculus in any way?

I can clearly see that the common ratio $r$ for $<nx^{n-1}>$ is $r=\dfrac{n+1}{n}x$, but unfortunately $n$ is variable and not a fixed constant and also $|r| < 1$ does not necessarily hold for me to be able to compute the infinte sum.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: The main "problem" here is to argue that you can interchange the derivate with the inifinte summation.

Comment: @NiklasHebestreit Sorry but I do not understand what you want to convey....

Comment: you can also expand the rhs into a tayloer series...

Comment: Of course this is linked to calculus, it is a common [Maclaurin series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions).

Comment: For $|x|<1$ we have the [negative binomial expansion](https://brilliant.org/wiki/negative-binomial-theorem/)$$(1-x)^{-2}=1+2x+\frac{2(2+1)x^2}{2!}+\frac{2(2+1)(2+2)}{3!}x^3+...$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{-2}{k}(-x)^k$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**By elementary means**:

$$S:=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)x^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^n+\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=xS+\frac1{1-x},$$ so that

$$S=\frac1{(1-x)^2}.$$

---

You can also discuss convergence by evaluating the partial sums and showing that the remainder decreases exponentially.

$$S_m:=\sum_{n=1}^m nx^{n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{m-1}(n+1)x^n=\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} nx^n+\sum_{n=0}^{m-1}x^n=xS_m-mx^m+\frac{1-x^m}{1-x},$$

$$S_m=-\frac{mx^m}{(1-x)}+\frac{1-x^m}{(1-x)^2}=S-\frac{mx^m}{(1-x)}-\frac{x^m}{(1-x)^2}.$$